# django-admin.py creating flat directory structure

Tags: python, django

So I have installed Django on my FreeBSD 8.2 box like this:

```
pip install django
```

I can verify that django works by typing:

```
python
>>> import django
```

I then upgrade my django to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

I check the version:

```
python
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)
```

So I got the latest version.

I then create a django project like this:

```
django-admin.py startproject helloworld
```

Everything works fine but the project structure created is flat - and the documentation says that if the created structure is flat I should update django to the latest version. But my django is the latest version. Why is the created directory structure flat?

It should look as described  here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

The created directory structure:

```
helloworld/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Should look like:

```
helloworld/
    manage.py
    helloworld/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Comment: just for info, can you post what exists inside `helloworld/`?

Comment: Just FYI - here are the release notes for Django 1.4 regarding the updated default directory structure: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't match what you see? The default project layout recently
>   changed. If you're seeing a "flat" layout (with no inner mysite/
>   directory), you're probably using a version of Django that doesn't
>   match this tutorial version. You'll want to either switch to the older
>   tutorial or the newer Django version.

You have 1.3.1 (latest stable release) and the docs are for trunk (1.4+ alpha as of today). The flat structure is what you should expect for 1.3.

[Here are the docs for version 1.3.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/)